# Validation state is not reactive (vue2) once I insert new object into an array

Tags: vuejs2, vuelidate

I have a row, which is an object with a few properties. This row is part of a form. This form is an array of rows.

I need to insert, let's say, a row in between the 2nd and the 3rd row. I'm using `splice` to do this.

The form itself is properly reactive, as expected (in vue2), but the validation state for the inserted row is not reactive (that is the errors are not checked/validated).

As a matter of fact, vuelidate works (it validates the errors in the row field) if I push a new row into the form/array (that is, I add it at the end of the array), but it doesn't work if i insert it in between two rows.

In the form component:

```js
<div v-for="(row, i) in form.rows">
    <row-comp
        row:="row"
        :i="i"
    />
</div>
```

The form:

```js
const form = {
     date: null,
     number: null,
     rows: []
}
```

The rows array in the form component (a form with multiple rows) in the form component:

```js
form.rows[0] = {
    item: null,
    quantity: 0,
    product: {
        name: null,
        code: null,
    },
}
```

To insert the new row at position i:

```js
form.rows.splice(i + 1, 0, row);
```

The new inserted row is properly hanled by vue but not by vuelidate, as the errors are not validated,

Note: if I add the new row to the end of the array it works: `form.push(row)` or `rows.splice(length + 1, 0, row)`

Comment: You are not using a `:key` with the `v-for`. Probably not the issue, but who knows. Please add `row-comp` and possibly a sandbox that shows the error.